# android java onClick Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

This is my first time working with the recyclerview and I am getting some errors about `android:onClick="addItem"` here is what I get when I try to add a line of text to my recyclerview. I usually use my phone to test my apps.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4012)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
            at com.sapps.app.testapp2.MainActivity.addItem(MainActivity.java:53)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Here is my code where I think is the error, but I don't know exactly:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText mText;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Button btn;
private CustomRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

private List<Data> mData = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializing views.
    mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEt);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    // If the size of views will not change as the data changes.
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Setting the LayoutManager.
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // Setting the adapter.
    CustomRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}



// Called when add button is clicked.
public void addItem(View v) {

    if(mText!=null) {
        Data dataToAdd = new Data(mText.getText().toString()); mData.add(dataToAdd);
    }
}
```

}

And here is my recyclerview adapter to know for sure:

```
public class CustomRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {

    CustomRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

    private List<Data> mData = Collections.emptyList();

    public CustomRecyclerAdapter() {
        // Pass context or other static stuff that will be needed.
    }

    public void updateList(List<Data> data) {
        mData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.title.setText(mData.get(position).text);
    }

    public void addItemInRec(int position, Data data) {
        mData.add(data);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mData.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
```

My MainActivity xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textEt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Text"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"
            android:onClick="addItem"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Maybe it is my ViewHolder:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView title;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}
```

Or Data.java class:

```
public class Data {

        public String text;
        public Data(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference` Is any of that error message confusing?

Comment: what can I do about it? I'm not a pro in debugging ;)

Comment: This line `at com.sapps.app.testapp2.MainActivity.addItem(MainActivity.java:53)` tells you **exactly** where the exception is... make sure your object is not null. It's pretty straightforward. It also means, this line `EditText mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEt);` is not executed before the button is pressed and that code is called. Since you didn't include the stuff before this, it's going to be hard to say.

Comment: do :  if(mText!=null) { Data dataToAdd = new Data(mText.getText().toString());
        mData.add(dataToAdd); } Also check why mText is null when you have initialized it above? maybe share your xml?

Comment: Ryan might be correct, maybe it is not yet initialized and you are clicking on add button

Answer (score 7):

The key is in your error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
            at com.sapps.app.testapp2.MainActivity.addItem(MainActivity.java:53)
```

A good tip for learning from your error output is to look at each "Caused by" statement, and scan through the log until you find one of your own files referenced.  Then that part of the error log will even tell you what line your code was failing on ( in this case it is line 53 on MainActivity.java).

A Null Pointer Exception in Java is when you attempt to call a method on some object 'A', but that object 'A' is currently `null`.

So this error message means:
"On line 53 of MainActivity.java, you tried to call a method on some object which doesn't exist yet, so I crashed."

The method that is failing is `EditText mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEt);`

Usually this type of failure means that you aren't finding the right ID from your layout.  Double check that `textEt` is the correct ID for this layout element.

**EDIT:**

Still not sure why your views aren't getting populated, but I did notice an error with your adapter.  You are redefining `mAdapter`, so you have 2 copies, one in local scope and one as a member to MainActivity. This will definitely mess things up.

Right here:

```
// Setting the adapter.
CustomRecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)
```

You are redefining `mAdapter` locally. Do this instead:

```
// Setting the adapter.
mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)
```

Comment: I have got already android:id="@+id/textEt" in my MainActivity.xml file. But could it be that my LinearLayout causes the error?

Comment: You can put a break point on line 53 of MainActivity.java. Double click on the left hand side of the file in the "gutter" and a little red dot will appear. Then instead of hitting the play button, hit the bug button.  When your code reaches that line, it will stop executing. Then you can check the values of all your layout, and see what is null and what is not.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of = null;

Comment: android.widget.EditText{1d699d85 VFED..CL ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f08003f app:id/textEt}

Comment: The "gutter" on any IDE like Android Studio is the space in between line numbers and code file, where you can add breakpoints http://thatjeffsmith.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/line_gutter1.png

Looks like you were able to get the debugger working.  If you are seeing a lot of null, sounds like the view isn't getting populated or something.

Can you edit your question to contain all of your MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 5):

You are getting a null pointer on the `getText()` call

It means the following line:

```
EditText mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEt);
```

returns null, solution is to check and correct the layout so that `textEt` is on it.

Edit:

If you are sure that it's in the layout remove `EditText` declaration.

Declare as `private EditText mText;` on the class scope

```
setContentView(R.layout.name_of_layout_here);
mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEt);
```

Comment: textEt is already in my mainactivity.xml file: `<EditText
            android:id="@+id/textEt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Text"/>`

Comment: @svenvdz so it means  you have another public variable that confict because `EditText mText` is declared in another scope. you need to show more code

Answer (score 0):

The view in `addItem(View v)` is referring to the button only.
The `EditText` object that you want is not in the button, it is in the button's parent view.
If you try to access the object from the button view it will be null, because the button does not have it.
Instead you need to access the object from the button's parent view.

```
// Solution:
public void addItem(View v) {
    View parentView = (View) v.getParent();
    EditText mText = (EditText) parentView.findViewById(R.id.textEt);
    Log.d("LOG", mText.getText().toString()));
}
```

I know that technically this does not solve the code in the question. But the code in the question has been changed from what produced the error so this would solve the original buggy code that actually produced the question.
I am guessing that the original buggy code looked like this:

```
// My guess this was the original buggy code
// MainActivity.java
public void addItem(View v) {
    EditText mText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.textEt);
    Data dataToAdd = new Data(mText.getText().toString());
    mData.add(dataToAdd);
}

// MainActivity.xml
<LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textEt"
    />

    <Button
        android:text="Add"
        android:onClick="addItem"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change public void addItemInRec to public void addItem. There is no method for onClick in mainActivity.