# Having error during read/write to file in my App

Tags: java, android, java-io

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.jaypatel.file;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.Buffer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void writeData(View view)
    {
        BufferedWriter bufferWriter = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("testFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));
            bufferWriter.write(((EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally
        {
            try {
                bufferWriter.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void readData(View view)
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("testFile");
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line=bufferReader.readLine())!=null){
                result.append(line + "\r\n");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ((EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText(result);
    }
}
```

**ERROR LOG:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jaypatel.file, PID: 3382
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.jaypatel.file.MainActivity.readData(MainActivity.java:65)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you update your question and post your activity_main.xml file? The onclick in there is causing your issue it looks like.

Comment: @srayhunter [button1]  android:onClick="writeData",[button2] android:onClick="readData"

Comment: Which button did you click for the stacktrace above?

Comment: @srayhunter I find enter something is field and i press write then when i try to read it by clicking "read" my app crashes.

Comment: I would debug and set a breakpoint here AppCompatViewInflater.java:293 and see what is in the exception. It is getting wrapped and viewing the exception there might tell you what the real exception is. Try that and post the any additional information.

Comment: see my answer below @user3801134

Answer (score 0):

I got your error, as you have declare two time buffer reader therefore it is showing null pointer exception,

**Just go through my below edited code it will work**

```
  public void readData(View view)
  {
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     try {
         FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("testFile");
         bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
         String line;
          while ((line=bufferReader.readLine())!=null){
              result.append(line + "\r\n");
         }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }finally {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ((EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `editText2`, you haven't initialized it. I prefer you to do the following:

1. Declare a private field `private EditText editText;`
2. Bind the view `(editText2)` inside `onCreate()` method like this

   `editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);`
3. Inside the `readData()` instead of
    `((EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText(result);`
    
   use this line of code:

   `this.editText.setText(result);`

Comment: i don't think this will cause any `NullPointer`..!! Do you??

Comment: most of the time IllegalStateException and InvocationTargetException are because this.

Comment: did you  give it a try ?

Comment: Do you find any real file name in the exception logs of  IllegalStateException and InvocationTargetException ?? I mean the file belongs to the project ?? NO.. so that exceptions are not real..!! see this for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29287325/6127411