# InvocationTargetException : Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android

I am new in Android and I want to put Click event on XML instead of java, and I have implemented following method on Activity class

```
   public void onInfoClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()) {

            case R.id.ivAcceptAmericanExpress:
                showPopup(v, getString(R.string.apt_american_express));
                break;
          }
    }
```

and in XML , I have done following code

```
 <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivAcceptAmericanExpress"
                    android:layout_width="24.286dp"
                    android:layout_height="24.286dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtAcceptAmericanExpress"
                    android:src="@drawable/info_image"
                    android:onClick="onInfoClick" />
```

but when I click on Image I am getting following error

```
Could not execute method of the activity
android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4021)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19873)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699):: Cause : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4016)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19873)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android java onClick Could not execute method of the activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287152/android-java-onclick-could-not-execute-method-of-the-activity)

Comment: This error usually points to an exception in the `onInfoClick` method - you can confirm this by commenting out your case-statement and see if you still get the error.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla thank you so much for your suggestion you are right when I have commented switch case and after tapping on textview app is not crashing, but i don't know what's wrong with that switch case even my textview has ID also

Comment: @AesSedai101 please read correctly before you post comment of duplicate

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla you are right! there is problem with  showPopup function now working fine, thanks a lot for your suggestion otherwise i never found what's wrong with my code

Comment: Great. I am glad I could help. I should probably convert my comment into an answer so you can accept to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InvocationTargetException` usually points to an exception in the `onClick` method which you are trying to execute - in your case the `onInfoClick` method - you can confirm this by commenting out your `case-statement` and see if you still get the error. Once you have identified the problem - you can make the necessary changes to resolve the exception. You should probably surround the body of the method with a `try-catch` to be safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot because of my limited points i can only accept the answer